# Multiprocessing Pool socked.timeout

Tags: python, sockets, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have a Python function that runs a single simulation through the WNTR package, which uses a DLL to crunch the numbers. When I try to parallelize the function (184 calls at a time for 11,000 simulations) with a multiprocessing.Pool I (nearly) simultaneously get several copies of the following at the start of the simulations and then every so often:

```
12.12s - Could not connect to 127.0.0.1: 58853
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/.vscode-server-insiders/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.12.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/_vendored/pydevd/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 493, in start_client
    s.connect((host, port))
socket.timeout: timed out
```

Below is the code that does the parallelization (sorry I can't provide a working example because the simulation data is confidential and a small example would run into different overhead issues):

```py
with get_context('forkserver').Pool(n_jobs) as p:
    results = p.map(partial_run_simulation, to_iterate_through_shuffled, chunksize=30)
```

I was having problems with the context `fork` not being able to get as many threads going and `spawn` was giving me the same error above. What is causing this and wow do I fix it? Is this just the debugger not being able to connect to the threads, in which case I'm good?